# override admin .phtml file in my design

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I got this file:

> /magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/button.phtml

I have put it there:

> /magento/app/design/adminhtml/UV/bgn_medienshop_2017_admin/Module_Backend/templates/widget/button.phml

Now it should always take the .phml in my design but it doesn't. Did I place it at the wrong position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the small mistake

`Module_Backend` Should be `Magento_Backend`.Otherwise, it seems ok.

As per as magento,`module-backend`  module name is [`Magento_Backend`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Backend/registration.php#L9),So `Module_Backend` Should be `Magento_Backend`.

Also template file extension is wrong, it should `button.phtml` from `button.phml`.Please check those properly.

Please changes the folder:

> /magento/app/design/adminhtml/UV/bgn_medienshop_2017_admin/Module_Backend/templates/widget/button.phtml

**to**

> /magento/app/design/adminhtml/UV/bgn_medienshop_2017_admin/Magento_Backend/templates/widget/button.phml

**Assume that your admin module is working properly**